# Installed PECL with sudo; How can I remove it?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

I installed PECL following this guide https://blackdeerdev.com/install-pecl-pear-on-mac-osx/

but with sudo..

it does not say in the script but since it did not work i wanted to try because the script did not work

now I have to sudo everything and I don't know how to uninstall and reinstall

Comment: The install instructions will only work as sudo - the installed things are installed for all users and so you need to use sudo to install. Being able to write to /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/pear is not easily possible (and on Apple Silicon very very difficult) so the install instructions are wrong. This is the standard Unix setup. So what is the issue?

Comment: I had to chown folders to my user and chmod 775. seems to work now